# Comparing Lists with different types for duplicates returns only one item

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have two Lists with data.
First list is of custom type TodayTask

```
todaysTodayTasks {
  task1 {title: "clean room", details: "dust, sweep, mop" ...}
  task1 {title: "shopping", details: "flour, carrots" ...}
}
```

Second list is of RepeatingTask Type but has a TodayTask property inside it.

```
repeatingTasks {
  task1 {repeatfreq:22, repeat:true, task: {title: "clean room", details: "dust, sweep, mop"} ... },
  task1 {repeatfreq:52, repeat:true, task: {title: "shopping", details: "flour, carrots"} ... },
}
```

Now what I want is to check if todaysTodayTasks list contains any of the entries in `repeatingTasks.task`. if it does not contain any of the repeating tasks, add those missing repeating tasks to todaysTodayTasks otherwise do nothing. For example to start with todaysTodayTasks only has the following entry:

```
todaysTodayTasks {
  task1 {title: "clean room", details: "dust, sweep, mop" ...}
}
```

So the code will add the following repeatingTasks list to todaysTodayTasks list which is

```
task1 {title: "shopping", details: "flour, carrots" ...}
```

Here the is code I currently have. Now it works when there is no entry to begin with, but when there are entries already inside todaysTodayTasks, it keeps adding entries from the repeatingtasks but starting from the 2nd entry. it detects that the first entry is there and doesnt add that. but adds the rest of the entries from the repeating task list.

```dart
    if (todaysTodayTasks.isEmpty) {
       print("today tasks empty.");
       for (RepeatingTask task in repeatingTasks) {
         if (task.TodayTask != null) {
           print("ADD REPEATING TASK FOR TODAY: ${task.TodayTask!.title}");
           //add task.TodayTask to todocolleciton here
           TodayTask newTodayTask = TodayTask(
               title: task.TodayTask!.title,
               details: task.TodayTask!.details,
               priority: task.TodayTask!.priority,
               isComplete: false,
               date: date,
               tags: task.TodayTask!.tags,
               isRepeating: true);
           writeTodoData(newTodayTask);
         }
       }
    }else{
     for (RepeatingTask task in repeatingTasks) {
       for (TodayTask item in todaysTodayTasks) {
         print("Current TodayTask: ${item.title}");
         print("Current Task: ${task.TodayTask!.title}");
         if (task.TodayTask != null) {
           if (item.title != task.TodayTask!.title &&
               item.details != task.TodayTask!.details) {
             print("ADD REPEATING TASK FOR TODAY: ${task.TodayTask!.title}");
             //add task.TodayTask to todocolleciton here
             TodayTask newTodayTask = TodayTask(
                 title: item.title,
                 details: item.details,
                 priority: item.priority,
                 isComplete: false,
                 date: date,
                 tags: item.tags,
                 isRepeating: true);
             writeTodoData(newTodayTask);
           }
         }
       }
     }
    }
```

[image: Expected vs actual]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a set of titles of TodayTasks in todaysTodayTasks list

```
Set<String> todayTaskTitles = Set<String>.from(todaysTodayTasks.map((task) => task.title));

for (RepeatingTask task in repeatingTasks) {
  if (task.TodayTask != null) {
    if (!todayTaskTitles.contains(task.TodayTask!.title)) {
      print("ADD REPEATING TASK FOR TODAY: ${task.TodayTask!.title}");
      // add task.TodayTask to todocolleciton here
      TodayTask newTodayTask = TodayTask(
          title: task.TodayTask!.title,
          details: task.TodayTask!.details,
          priority: task.TodayTask!.priority,
          isComplete: false,
          date: date,
          tags: task.TodayTask!.tags,
          isRepeating: true);
      writeTodoData(newTodayTask);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it with sets, but I guess I did something wrong somewhere. thank you!